# вывести значения из массива, сохраненного как строка

Tags: php

подскажите, как вывести значения отсюда?

```
["40-46","42-48"]

echo $result['size'];
foreach($result['size'] as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

из базы я получаю вот так размеры:

```
["40-46,"42-48"]
[42]
["42-48"]
[42,44,46,48]
[42,44]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как именно вывести? просто вывести чувак написал как. если неправильно то напиши как надо. ожидаемый результат какой?

Comment: так и нужно, но у меня не выводит вообще результат с foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(json_decode($result['size']) as $item) {
  echo $item."<br>";
}
```

Comment: это сработало, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если в столбик тогда вот так:

```
$arr = ["40-46","42-48"];
foreach($arr as $item) {
  echo $item."<br>";
}
```

Comment: добавил в вопрос, так не выводит

Comment: @extrememod так как я написал — выводит

Comment: гляньте плз вопрос, забыл добавить, как получаю из базы

Comment: это модуль так формирует в modx) вот я и не знаю как это вывести